# php array implode explode with symbol

Tags: php, arrays

my code is

```
$arr = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$str = implode(',', $arr);
echo $str;
```

original output is : `item1,item2,item3`

but i need the output like this : `'item1','item2','item3'`

Any idea

Comment: What data format are you trying to produce here exactly? While there's a literal, easy answer to your question, I have the feeling this is only part of a wrong approach to a bigger problem.

Comment: @deceze The format is String, as implode gives a string.

Comment: @Theolodis Uhm, d'uh? I mean, `'item1','item2','item3'` doesn't look like something that's supposed to be for the UI, it looks like he's trying to create a string in a certain format, be that JSON or SQL or something.

Comment: suppose he's trying to format the array to put in a sql statement with  `IN`. implode with quotes is a solution.

Comment: @Volkan That's what I'm driving at; this may be the wrong approach if he's not taking proper escaping into account and/or when he should be using parameterised queries.

Comment: @deceze you might be right with the SQL, but it's still a string. I don't see why this would be relevant?
edit: maybe he has his array items escaped already?

Comment: @Theolodis *"It's all just text"*? [No, it isn't.](http://kunststube.net/escapism)

Comment: @deceze if he has his items escaped already I don't see the point. It is just text. and if the items are escaped, then it is escaped text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `','` instead of just `,`.

Try this:

```
$arr = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$str = "'" . implode("','", $arr) . "'";
echo $str;
```

Comment: You would need to do `echo "'" . $str . "'";`

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$str   = implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $array));
function add_quotes($str) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you can set your own wrappers in case you need to reuse the code in some other parts.

```
function implode_wrapper($split, $arr, $wrapper)
{
    $aux = $arr;
    foreach ($aux as $key=>$value)
    {
        $arr[$key] = $wrapper . $value . $wrapper;
    }
    $str = implode($split, $arr);

    return $str;
}

$arr = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$str = implode_wrapper(",", $arr, "'");
echo $str;
```